# Java program that compute the average salary of 20 workers

Tags: java

I've been stuck on this a while, a Java program to compute average salary of 20 workers and this what I came up with so far. .............................................................................................................................................................

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Employee
{
    int age;
    String name, address, gender;
    Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
    Employee()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Name of the Employee:");
        name = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Gender of the Employee:");
        gender = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Address of the Employee:");
        address = get.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter Age:");
        age = get.nextInt();
    }

    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Employee Name: "+name);
        System.out.println("Age: "+age);
        System.out.println("Gender: "+gender);
        System.out.println("Address: "+address);
    }
}

class fullTimeEmployees extends Employee
{
    float salary;
    int des;
    fullTimeEmployee()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Designation:");
        des = get.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Salary:");
        salary = get.nextFloat();
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("=============================="+"\n"+"Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"=============================="+"\n");
        super.display();
        System.out.println("Salary: "+salary);
        System.out.println("Designation: "+des);
    }
}

class partTimeEmployees extends Employee
{
    int workinghrs, rate;
    partTimeEmployees()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Number of Working Hours:");
        workinghrs = get.nextInt();
    }
    void calculatepay()
    {
        rate = 8 * workinghrs;
    }

    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("=============================="+"\n"+"Part Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"=============================="+"\n");
        super.display();
        System.out.println("Number of Working Hours: "+workinghrs);
        System.out.println("Salary for "+workinghrs+" working hours is: $"+rate);
    }
}

class Employees
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
        fullTimeEmployees ob1 = new fullTimeEmployees();
        partTimeEmployees ob = new partTimeEmployees();
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter Part Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
        ob1.display();
        ob.calculatepay();
        ob.display();
    }
}
```

Your assistance is much appreciated!

Comment: If I answer your question, will you add me to your payroll?

Comment: What isn't working? Are there errors?

Comment: what is problem ?

Comment: the code above is only for a single employee, i want the one for 20 workers

Comment: use loop to do it. Loop your main class code from 1-20.

Answer (score 0):

change constructor `fullTimeEmployee` to `fullTimeEmployees`

```
class fullTimeEmployees extends Employee
{
    float salary;
    int des;
    fullTimeEmployees()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Designation:");
        des = get.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Salary:");
        salary = get.nextFloat();
    }
    void display()
    {
        System.out.println("=============================="+"\n"+"Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"=============================="+"\n");
        super.display();
        System.out.println("Salary: "+salary);
        System.out.println("Designation: "+des);
    }
}
```

This works for one employee. if you want to do same for 20 employees then use loop;

```
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
        fullTimeEmployees[] fullTimeEmployees= new fullTimeEmployees[20];
        partTimeEmployees[] partTimeEmployees= new partTimeEmployees[20];

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
          System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
          fullTimeEmployees[i] = new fullTimeEmployees();
          System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter Part Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
          partTimeEmployees[i] = new partTimeEmployees();
        }
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
        for(int i=0 ;i<20;i++){
          fullTimeEmployees[i].display();
        }
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Part Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
        for(int i=0 ;i<20;i++){
          partTimeEmployees[i].calculatepay();
          partTimeEmployees[i].display();
        }

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

add an abstract method in Employee which returns the salary:

```
public abstract int getSalary();
```

And implement it in each subclass:

```
// class names start with upper case character
class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee
{
    // don't use float, represent money in cents (and you should maybe represent the currency separately)
    int salary;
    // 'des' is not clear
    int designtation;
    fullTimeEmployee()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter Designation:");
        designtation = get.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter Salary:");
        salary = get.nextInt();

    public abstract int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
```

Why is `rate = 8 & workingHours`?

To calculate the average, keep track of the total salary and the number of employees counted whilst iterating over each employe:

```
    int count = 0;
    int totalSalary = 0;    
    Employee emp; 
    while (emp = getEmployee() != null) {
        count++;     
        totalSalary += emp.getSalary();
    }
    double avgSalary = totalSalary / count;
    System.out.println("Avg salary: " + avgSalary);
}

private Employee getEmployee() {
    Employeee emp = null;
    System.out.println("Part time or full time employee? any other key to quit (p/f):");
    String input = get.nextString();
    if ("f".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter     Full Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
        emp = new FullTimeEmployee();
    }
    else if ("p".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
        emp = new PartTimeEmployee();
        System.out.println("================================"+"\n"+"Enter Part Time Employee Details"+"\n"+"================================"+"\n");
    }
    return emp;
}
```